# Как написать условие активации того или иного значения в QComboBox?

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qcombobox, qtextbrowser

Допустим, у меня в `QComboBox` есть **две** ячейки - "Собаки" и "Коты".
И я хочу реализовать условие: 
Если выбрали ячейку коты, то пиши "Вы любите котов" в `QTextBrowser`, 
иначе, если вы выбрали ячейку собаки, то пишите "Вы любите собак" в `QTextBrowser`.

И у меня возникает вопрос о том, как это реализовать. Желательно на примере кода.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Graph22 import Ui_MainWindow
from Settings import Ui_Dialog
from Description2 import Ui_Dialog_3


class MyWin2(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.nFunc)
        self.n = 0

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_D:
            self.mywin3 = MyWin3()
            mw3 = self.mywin3
            mw3.show()
            self.mywin3.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.mywin3.hide)
        else:
            super(MyWin2, self).keyPressEvent(e)

    def nFunc(self):
        self.n = int(self.ui.lineEdit.text())
        print("self.n-", self.n)


class MyWin3(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog_3()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.SetBut)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Chif)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.ReChif)
        self.n = 0

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_D:
            self.mywin3 = MyWin3()
            mw3 = self.mywin3
            mw3.show()
            self.mywin3.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.mywin3.hide)
        else:
            super(MyWin, self).keyPressEvent(e)

    def SetBut(self):
        self.mywin2 = MyWin2()
        self.mywin2.show()
        self.mywin2.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.okClicked)
        self.mywin2.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.mywin2.hide)

    def okClicked(self):
        self.n = self.mywin2.n
        print("def okClicked->", self.n)
        self.mywin2.hide()

    def Chif(self):
        self.ui.textBrowser_2.setText("")

        eng = ' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
        rus = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя"
        ENG = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        RUS = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ"
        nums = " 1234567890"
        s = self.ui.textEdit.toPlainText()

        n = self.n

        res = ''
        print("s->", s)
        for i in s:
            if i in rus:
                res += rus[(rus.index(i) + n) % len(rus)]
            elif i in eng:
                res += eng[(eng.index(i) + n) % len(eng)]
            elif i in RUS:
                res += RUS[(RUS.index(i) + n) % len(RUS)]
            elif i in ENG:
                res += ENG[(ENG.index(i) + n) % len(ENG)]
            elif i in nums:
                res += nums[(nums.index(i) + n) % len(nums)]
            else:

                print("Символ `{}` не шифруется?".format(i))
                res += i

        kp = 'Result: "' + res + '"'

        self.ui.textBrowser_2.setText(kp)

    def ReChif(self):
        self.ui.textBrowser_2.setText("")

        eng = ' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
        rus = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя"
        ENG = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        RUS = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ"
        nums = " 1234567890"
        s = self.ui.textEdit.toPlainText()

        n = self.n

        res = ''
        print("s->", s)
        for i in s:
            if i in rus:
                res += rus[(rus.index(i) - n) % len(rus)]
            elif i in eng:
                res += eng[(eng.index(i) - n) % len(eng)]
            elif i in RUS:
                res += RUS[(RUS.index(i) - n) % len(RUS)]
            elif i in ENG:
                res += ENG[(ENG.index(i) - n) % len(ENG)]
            elif i in nums:
                res += nums[(nums.index(i) - n) % len(nums)]
            else:

                print("Символ `{}` не шифруется?".format(i))
                res += i

        kp = 'Result: "' + res + '"'

        self.ui.textBrowser_2.setText(kp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Вверху была основная программа. Сейчас добавлю ее графическую составляющую.
**P.S** 
При выборе отй или иной ячейки у меня должно выходить описание того или
иного метода шифрования.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog_3(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(613, 142)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 110, 141, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Dialog)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 0, 141, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Dialog)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 471, 141))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Выйти"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Dialog", "Цезарь"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Dialog", "Литорея"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("Dialog", "Индексация"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("Dialog", "Метод 4"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("Dialog", "Метод 5"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("Dialog", "Метод 6"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("Dialog", "Метод 7"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("Dialog",
                                            "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
                                            "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
                                            "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
                                            "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
                                            "<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: А что у вас не получилось?

Comment: В том то и дело, что я не пробовал это реализовать. Я не знаю команд, которые позволят это сдлеать.

Comment: По вашему вопросу мне показалось что у вас есть ComboBox и TextBrowser )

Comment: Я это создал с помощью QtDesigner'a, поэтому ваш ответ немного не совпадает моими реалиями, к сожалению. Не могли бы вы показать это пример без создания виджетов, просто демонстрация функций, которая позволит мне это сделать. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Мой код почти неизменится. `<ваш_комбобокс>.currentIndexChanged.connect(self._on_pet_changed)` и проверяйте по index кого выбрал пользователь. `if index == 0: <выбрали собаку>` это все я подробно расписал в ответе. Пробуйте

Comment: Сейчас добавлю грфическую часть моей программы и сам "скелет" программы.

Comment: А собаки с кошками были для примера? Оо

Comment: Да, для примера)

Comment: У вас отступы разъехались, код невалидный стал

Comment: Это пришлоась сделать, чтобы код загрузился на сайт. В начальной(верной) конфигурации этот редактор не принимал мой код

Comment: Копируйте в редактор, а после на сайт. Так проще будет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, вы мастер задавать вопросы :）
Пример на вашем модуле `Description2.py`:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog_3(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(613, 142)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 110, 141, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Dialog)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 0, 141, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
# +++        
        self.comboBox.activated['int'].connect(self.on_activated)   # +++

        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Dialog)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 471, 141))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Выйти"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Dialog", "Цезарь"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Dialog", "Литорея"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("Dialog", "Индексация"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("Dialog", "Метод 4"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("Dialog", "Метод 5"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("Dialog", "Метод 6"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("Dialog", "Метод 7"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("Dialog",
                                            "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
                                            "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
                                            "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
                                            "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
                                            "<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
# +++
    def on_activated(self, index):
        if index == 0:
            self.textBrowser.setHtml("Цезарь ...")
        elif index == 1:
            self.textBrowser.setHtml("Литорея ...")
        elif index == 2:
            self.textBrowser.setHtml("Индексация ...") 
        elif index == 3:
            self.textBrowser.setHtml("Метод 4 ...")             
        elif index == 4:
            self.textBrowser.setHtml("Метод 5 ...") 
        elif index == 5:
            self.textBrowser.setHtml("Метод 6 ...") 
        elif index == 6:
            self.textBrowser.setHtml("Метод 7 ...")             

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog_3()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Опередили меня, буквально на пару минут :)

Comment: Спасибо большое) Такими темпами вы всю программу за меня напишите)

Comment: @gil9red ваш ответ будет полезен многим, как и мне. А автору хочется пожелать, чтобы вопросы соответствовали проблемам конкретного кода и сразу размещать этод код.

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTextBrowser, QComboBox, QVBoxLayout


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tb_result = QTextBrowser()

        self.cb_pets = QComboBox()
        self.cb_pets.currentIndexChanged.connect(self._on_pet_changed)
        self.cb_pets.addItem('Собаки', userData='dogs')
        self.cb_pets.addItem('Коты', userData='cats')

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.cb_pets)
        layout.addWidget(self.tb_result)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def _on_pet_changed(self, index):
        data = self.cb_pets.itemData(index)

        if data == 'cats':
            text = "Вы любите кошек"
        elif data == 'dogs':
            text = "Вы любите собак"
        else:
            text = ''

        self.tb_result.setHtml(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**PS.** если несколько способов проверять данные.

- Первое - по индексу.
- Второе - по текущему индексу. Например, когда сработает сигнал `currentIndexChanged` текущий элемент поменяется и мы сможем через методы `.current...()` получить нужную инфу. А метод, что будет соединен с `currentIndexChanged` может и не принимать параметр `index`.

А по поводу проверки данных, то решить ее можем несколькими способами:

- Проверять по индексу. Например, когда мы заполняем комбобокс, мы знаем что под 0 индексом будут "Собаки", а под 1 - "Кошки"
- Проверять по данным. Когда мы добавляем элемент, мы можем привязать к нему какие-то данные. Для наглядности я добавлял туда определенные строки, но это может быть, к примеру, `enum`
- Проверять по тексту. Самый ненадежный способ, но тоже рабочий.

Наглядный пример:

```
def _on_pet_changed(self, index):
    print(index)                          # 0
    print(self.cb_pets.itemText(index))   # Собаки
    print(self.cb_pets.itemData(index))   # dogs
    print()
    print(self.cb_pets.currentIndex())    # 0
    print(self.cb_pets.currentText())     # Собаки
    print(self.cb_pets.currentData())     # dogs
```

Answer (score 0):

В `Ui_Dialog_3` генерируется и описывается интерфейс.

А в `MyWin3` добавляем логику для работы с интерфейсом.

Пример:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

# Копировать Ui_Dialog_3 из вопроса
# class Ui_Dialog_3(object):
#    ...
#

class MyWin3(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog_3()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self._on_cb_changed)

    def _on_cb_changed(self, index):
        if index == 0:
            text = "Вы любите цезарь. Выбрано: " + self.ui.comboBox.itemText(index)
        elif index == 1:
            text = "Вы любите Литорея. Выбрано: " + self.ui.comboBox.itemText(index)
        elif index == 2:
            text = "Вы любите Индексация. Выбрано: " + self.ui.comboBox.itemText(index)
        # elif index == 3:
        #   ...

        self.ui.textBrowser.setHtml(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin3()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]